# Android Library To Show Closable Tips

Tags: android, android-library

In my android application, I would like to show small introductory tips for different features but I don’t want to be intrusive by showing them dialogs. What I want is something similar to:

[image]

Sorry for poor design but I hope it’s clear to understand. I want a small bar beneath ActionBar/Toolbar which shows the desired text and a close button aligned right. Clicking this cross button will permanently hide the tip.

Is there some library exists for such purpose or there’s room for something like this?

This will be much better way for applications to express their features without being intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a modified SnackBar like [this](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar)

Comment: I think it won’t persist and will automatically close in few seconds. Persistance is in Todo list there

Comment: Just call `snackbar.setIndeterminate(true);` before calling `.show()`, or   just call it like `snackbar.make(layout, "abc", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);`